# Does CSS selector .class-xyz:not(.class-xyz) ever match?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Given any CSS with a selector like:

```
.class-xyz:not(.class-xyz) {
  ...
}
```

Is it possible that it ever matches any element?

What about augmenting it with things like `::after`, `::placeholder` and so on?

My intent is to simplify a bunch of huge CSS sheets, with lots of selectors like this.

Comment: Its like asking which are the elements with class `.class-xyz`, but not class `.class-xyz`

Comment: That's what I thought, a kind of `A & ¬A` (a contradiction), but I'm no CSS master. I was thinking about some CSS kinky rule that could make it match.

Comment: The question is: who wrote such CSS at the first place? maybe there is a *hidden* intention behind. It would be good to share your real CSS code

Comment: No hidden intention. Such a CSS is the result of a previous manipulation. I've listed all the classes that had no real use, and renamed them to `.CANARY`. Now I've got a bunch of .CANARY:not(.CANARY). I found it funny and was left thinking if I could use such constructions to simplify it further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That selector will not match any element, regardless of namespace (since, even with namespaces present, the outside `.class-xyz` represents the default namespace, and the one inside the negation always considers the same namespace as the outside selector).

Since that selector will not match any element, it follows that no pseudo-element will be matched. For a pseudo-element to apply, elements need to be matched in the first place.

If you wish to hide a CSS rule without outright deleting the rule or tampering with the original portion of the selector, a shorter way to do so using the negation pseudo-class would be `:not(*)` (or, if namespaces are present, `:not(*|*)`). This use case is explicitly given in the level [3](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#negation) and [4](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#negation) specs.

But the shortest *and clearest* way to hide a CSS rule by far is to comment it out.